# Capybara checking HTML class and ID

Tags: css, ruby, selenium, xpath, capybara

I'm currently trying to find this element and have capybara validate that it's there. There's an element that shows up and I'm using page.should have_css to see if this element is there.

```
<i class="ui-grid-icon-cancel" ui-grid-one-bind-aria-label="aria.removeFilter" aria-label="Remove Filter">&nbsp;</i>
```

I'm currently trying to get to the ui-grid-icon-cancel and validate that it's there. Here is the code I'm using to validate it.

```
page.should have_css('class#ui-grid-icon-cancel')
```

What else can I do to fix this.

I'm expecting to validate the CSS element using capybara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the other answers are correct about the needed CSS selectors, however if you're getting errors about `should` being undefined then you either haven't installed RSpec correctly or your project has the `should` syntax disabled - https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/syntax-configuration. The `should` syntax is going to be disabled by default in RSpec 4, and any new code really shouldn't be using it at this point. Instead you should be using the `expect` syntax. Any of the following should work, assuming you have RSpec properly installed, depending on exactly what you're trying to verify

```
expect(page).to have_css('.ui-grid-icon-cancel')
expect(page).to have_css('i.ui-grid-icon-cancel')
expect(page).to have_css('i', class: 'ui-grid-icon-cancel')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `page.should have_css('.ui-grid-icon-cancel')` . When looking for a class element, you need to use the notation of a period rather then explicitly putting the word "class".
`

Comment: I'm getting this error while doing .should have Failure/Error: page.should have_css('i[aria-label="Remove Filter"]') NoMethodError: undefined method `should' for #<Capybara::Session>

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- *css_selector* using value of *class* attribute:

  ```
  page.should have_css('i.ui-grid-icon-cancel')
                         ^ here dot denotes classname
  ```
- *css_selector* using value of *aria-label* attribute:

  ```
  page.should have_css('i[aria-label="Remove Filter"]')
  ```

Comment: I'm getting this error while doing .should have
Failure/Error: page.should have_css('i[aria-label="Remove Filter"]')
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `should' for #<Capybara::Session>

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.